# Error executing find command through Runtime.getRuntime().exec()

Tags: java, unix

I face an issue while executing the command below from Java

```
Process p2 = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("find /home/app/reports/ATM.CCC.* -mtime +1000");
```

I need to find files with the format `ATM.CCC.` which are older than 1000 days.
Also need to delete files older than 100 days.

Comment: Seems like not java-related. Is your command actually executed?

Comment: And what is the issue?

Answer (score 2):

I assume that you want `/home/app/reports/ATM.CCC.*` to be expanded to a list of files.

That won't work because "globbing" is a shell function, and not a core system function performed by the `exec` syscall ... or the Java `exec(...)` methods.

What you need to do is run the command in a shell; e.g.

```
.... exec(new String[]{
             "sh", "-c",
             "find /home/app/reports/ATM.CCC.* -mtime +1000"
          });
```

---

Note that you need to use the overload of `exec` that takes an array of strings.  If you attempt to use overload that takes a String and splits it into argument ... like this ...

```
.... exec("sh -c \"find /home/app/reports/ATM.CCC.* -mtime +1000\"");
```

the command string won't be split correctly.  (The `exec` splitter doesn't understand Unix / Linux shell-style quoting.)